Problem to make the LTC3105 boost the input voltage
I am having problems with the LTC3105 circuit. In the image you can see the schematic of my design and the schematic that I use as a reference. I am using a 2.5F input capacitor and right now I am testing the circuit without the load.

For the MPPC resistor I am using a potentiometer to change the value more easily. The idea is that the input voltage should be around 0.25V, so the potentiometer value usually is less than 25k.
As for the LDO voltage, I have been adjusting the resistor divider to find the one that works best, but it seems that no mater what resistor divider I use, it never achieve a total regulation and usualy ends in a voltage less than expected.
When I supply the circuit with a 0.25V or greater the output and aux voltage ends in a similar tension usually less than expected.
Here you have some examples of how the circuit works, in this case the MPPC resistor is set to 20k and the FBLDO pin is connected to gnd to test if VLDO can achieve 2.2V of regulation.
When Vin=0.45V then Vout=0.80V, Vaux=0.9V, VFLDO=0.13V.
When Vin=1V then Vout varies between 1.15V and 1.57V, Vaux varies between 1.20 and 1.67V, VBLDO varies between 0 and 1.10V. In this case the input current oscillates between 0.02 and 0.1A.
The closest to regulation that I could get was with an input voltage of 2.5V and then the VBLDO voltage was around 2.19V. Still, since I want to work with voltages as low as 0.25V, it doesn’t seem very useful.
I have also test using the FBLDO pin using a resistor divider but the result is mostly the same, the output voltage still can't reach 3.3V.
In the simulations the circuit works fine with this settings so I am guessing that it's someting about the manufactured version.
I have already try using other LTC3105 or changing the complete PCB layout but the result is the same.
Also I tried to use an ArduinoUNO to give an input voltage of 3.3V only to see if I can make the booster works and then switch to a source with less voltage and see if the IC could still be working but when I connect the ArduinoUNO the input pin in the IC literally started to burn.
Hope you have some idea of what can be wrong. I have been fighting with this circuit for quite some time and run out of ideas to try.
Edit:
Here is the layout of the PCB, the principal difference in comparison with the datasheet schematic is the size of the input capacitor and the use of a potentiometer.


As for a clearer description of what my problem is:
The IC needs to have the behavior of the following image

The problem is that even when Vaux has not reached 1.4V I can see that Vaux and Vout are at a voltage approximately equal which is usually less than 1V when the input voltage is less than 1V. Also, the VLDO doesn't achieve the regulation voltage required (in the example above it should be 2.2V). I can't understand exactly what can be wrong with the circuit, since Vout is equal to Vaux the IC should be in the regulation state but Vaux and VLDO voltage doesn't have the required value to actually be in that state.
Maybe some of you have a similar problem with this or another DC-DC converter and have some tips of what the cause of this strange behavior could be.
I don't have the waveforms of my design since I only measure the voltage using a common voltmeter.
Hope that it clarifies a little more the problem.
Edit 2:
Sorry for taking so much time to add more information.
Here is the BOM of the project:

Supercapacitor: SCMS22H255PRBB0
10uF capacitor :CMP-2006-02241-1
10uH inductor: LBR2012T100K
1uF capacitor: C0603C105K9PAC7867
470k resistor: CRCW0805470KFKEA
1.02M resistor: CPF0805B1M02E1
Booster: LTC3105EMS#PBF
4.7uF capacitor: C0805C475K8PACTU
1M resistor: CRCW08051M00FKEAHP
1.3M resistor: CRCW08051M30FKEA

As for other things that I tried without results. I made the external circuit of the evaluation board to see if it works. Since it was a simple test, I used a protoboard to connect the components, but I had no results with it.
Hope that someone have another idea about the problem.

That's the problem with simulations. They don't include parasitic trace inductance or ESL, crosstalk from the inductor to everything or the actual RLC value of every capacitor.  Since your schematic does not resemble the tight arrangement of parts in the datasheet, I have to assume the board layout has similar problems. So we need all your important scope measurements and board layout to find the problem.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Like previous comment said, simulations will only get you so far. You still actually need to understand what's going on.

Either modify the input parts on SIM to match Rs V, C to match your scope  measurements (assuming you have access to one) to break your a simulation or fix your schematic to match the board or fix the design.  But we need better data.. BOM, pix

What’s the part number of L1?

i.e. add your PV current source [A] add 2.5F ESR then add DCR of L and run simulation (then wait.....(;

Your layout is not exactly ideal.
